# Does "like" require an "etc." along with it?

Tags: word-usage

I got into a disagreement with a friend about this. Does the word "like" require an "etc." used with it if we're describing some of many objects?

For example, let's consider seven places A, B, C, D, E, F and G.

Which of these forms of description is more correct?

> Diamonds can be found in many places, like A, B and C.

> Diamonds can be found in many places, like A, B, C etc.

Comment: The example is more suited to "such as" (an inclusive list) than "like" (exclusive), although the latter is sometimes found in informal contexts.

Comment: The example is indeed more suited to "such as", but not because of an inclusive/exclusive difference. Rather "such as" introduces a list of examples, whereas "like" introduces a list of similarities.  It is not so uncommon to use "like" where "such as" would be a better fit, but that does blur the meaning a bit.

Comment: None of the answers have mentioned this, so I'm wondering if I've been misinformed over the years, but I'd been instructed along the lines of ["Don’t use etc. to end a list that begins with e.g., since it is by definition a list of examples."](https://ispe.org/pharmaceutical-engineering/january-february-2017/other-words-ie-eg-et-al-etc). If "like" in the question is intended with the same meaning as "such as", then this advice would seem to apply.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it isn't necessary to add *etcetera* to the end of a list of examples. By using *like* you are already indicating that A, B and C are only some of the places in question.

You could instead say

> Diamonds are found in A, B, C etc.

indicating that there are other places where diamonds are found.

Comment: In careful usage I would would use "like" only to introduce an archetype whose characteristics can be extrapolated. So, "sandstorms are a constant danger in deserts like the Sahara" makes sense. But "diamonds are found in places like Russia and South Africa" ... those places aren't "like" each other, much less wherever else diamonds are found (except of course for the diamonds). The phrasing in this answer is much better.

Comment: Russia and South Africa are "like" each other in that they have rich diamond producing volcanic pipes right?

Comment: @CCTO You are interpreting "like" to mean "sharing characteristics with," in which case you might be correct. But "like" in this context can also mean "such as." It just indicates that we are giving examples of places that have diamonds, without any claim that those places have any similarities to other places where diamonds may be found.

Comment: I don't like the use of *et cetera* here at all, because it's not obvious how to continue to extrapolate. If you say "the Whole Numbers are the numbers we count with: 1, 2, 3, etc." it's obvious how to generate more examples. But if you say "diamonds are found in A, B, C, and so on", I have no idea what "so on" refers to unless I already know where diamonds are found!

Comment: @JounceCracklePop - I'm not sure that the use of _et cetera_ necessarily means that the reader has to know what the 'other things' are - it just indicates that there _are_ others.

Comment: As this is the English SE, I'll mention that the standard formatting of "et cetera" is with a space between the words ("et" and "cetera" are separate Latin words).

Comment: @CCTO You dropped the comma, which changes the meaning. "Sandstorms are a constant danger in deserts like the Sahara" means "Sandstorms are a constant danger in deserts that are like the Sahara". "Sandstorms are a constant danger in deserts, like the Sahara" means "Sandstorms are a constant danger in deserts, and Sahara is an example of a desert where sandstorms are a constant danger".

Answer (score 17):

When we use "like", we are not giving an exhaustive list.
So if I say, "Dairy products are foods like milk and cheese", I am not saying that milk and cheese are the only dairy products; I am saying that milk and cheese are examples of dairy products but there are others.

Similarly, "etc" is also used for non-exhaustive lists:
"Dairy products include milk, cheese etc."
Here again, I am not saying that there are no dairy products other than milk and cheese.

So I would say that using "etc" (which follows a non-exhaustive list) with "like" (which precedes a non-exhaustive list of examples) is almost always superfluous.

Comment: Even in your example "etc" is superfluous: "Dairy products include milk and cheese" works the same.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Right, "includes" also implies that the list is not exhaustive. You would use "etc." if you said "Dairy products *are* milk, cheese, etc."

Comment: To be clear, it's not *wrong* to use both "like" and "etc.", just redundant and unnecessary.  At worst, it just seems slightly wordier than it has to be, but that doesn't make it incorrect or even unnatural-sounding to use both.

Answer (score 2):

No, this construction is often used without a final item like “etc.,” “et cetera” or “and so on.”  One has never been required in English.

An example going back to Chaucer’s *Canterbury Tales*:

> For ther he was nat lyk a cloysterer
>
> With a thredbare cope, as is a povre scoler,
>
> But he was lyk a maister or a pope.

**Edit:** This answer was migrated over from another site.  If you’re learning English, I hope the first paragraph was helpful!  But don’t worry about reading Chaucer in the original Middle English.